# Verious Database Connectivity in Vlang with ORM?

Tags: orm, nosql, rdbms, vlang

Is there any `hack` || `way` in `V-language` default `ORM` to support `MongoDB`?
Currently, I'm able to connect `PostgreSQL` as it supports it as a default `DB`. This is just the `RDBMS` part, But what if we want to connect `NoSQL`?

Also, I'm not able to connect `MySQL` as well as other `RDBMS` databases. I'll also share my thoughts in the answer section(If I get some). If you got any `hack` / `Ideas` then please post it below. As this language is new and the community is growing, Your answer and thoughts will be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since your answer, Vlang now has an [official driver for MongoDB](https://github.com/vlang/mongo).

Answer (score 0):

By now (dec 2020) there are no way to connect to a mongodb database, as of the page of the project on [github](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#orm). The support for other RDBMS is planned, but NoSQL databases have no plan to be added. But, if there are source code, there are a way todo, and maybe somebody can contribute adding this feature  ;-).